# Con solo CSS: ¿Como puedo: capturar el resultado de un link en una ventana?

Tags: css

Utilizando solo CSS:
Quiero colocar en una ventana, dentro de mi web, el resultado de un enlace a otra pagina web... Cuando de un click en el enlace, por ejemplo,

```
<a href="https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaticano" target="_blank">El Vaticano</a>
```

El contenido de la pagina enlazada, se muestre en una ventana modal.

He probado modificando el atributo `target = "framename"` y creando el frameset pero solo logro que me abra la web en la ventana definida, ¿Quizás sea posible decirle que el frame sea mi ventana modal, como lo hago?

Quiero que el resultado lo haga en una ventana modal.

Como sugiere la imagen siguiente:

[image: Resultado de un enlace]

Es esto posible?, quizás esté pidiendo demasiado, mis disculpas si es el caso

Comment: Explica mejor tu pregunta y por favor también añade que has intentado

Comment: Quieres pedir la pagina y posteriormente colocar todo ese marcado como si fuese otro contenido mas en un modal?

Comment: Exactamente, es eso lo que busco, gracias Ana Todd